# PyQt5 custom widget split backghround?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5, qwidget

I have had this happening multiple times. When I create a custom widget with an image in it all child widgets get seperated. How do I prevent that?

Full code that has the same outcome:

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import * 
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import * 
import sys

class CustomWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(CustomWidget, self).__init__()
        self.layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

        self.setStyleSheet(r'QWidget {background-color:#353634;}')

        self.name_label = QLabel('name')
        self.qty_label = QLabel('999')
        self.image_pix = QPixmap(IMAGEPATH)
        self.image_pix = self.image_pix.scaled(48, 48)
        self.icon = QLabel()
        self.icon.setPixmap(self.image_pix)

        self.layout.addWidget(self.icon)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.name_label)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.qty_label)



class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.width, self.height = 425,350
        self.resize(self.width, self.height)

        custom_widget = CustomWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(custom_widget)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = MainWindow()
    win.show()
    app.exec()
    app.quit()
```

[image: Image of split widget]

Comment: The image doesn't completely reflect the code you've shown, and it probably inherits some other style sheet set on parent or the application. Please provide a [mre].

Comment: I have updated the post with the full code that has the same outcome

Comment: Are you saying that if you don't set the image of the first label, there is no margin between the three widgets?

Comment: If there was no space between the widgets, that would be a bug, since layouts usually have a default spacing. To remove it, simply do `layout.setSpacing(0)`.

Comment: Thank you very much  layout.setSpacing(0) seems to have done the trick!